# How to convert Lambda Expression into SQL exp?

Tags: c#, sql, lambda, linq-to-entities

I am having difficulty converting this expression to SQL expression. I tried various applications but I failed. I tried to convert it myself but the result is different.

```
db.Trans_SAPStat.Where(s => s.EmployeeID == EmployeeID && s.PaymentID != PaymentID && !s.Status.Equals("cancelled or", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                           .Join(_db.Trans_PaymentDetail,
                                               stat => stat.PaymentID,
                                               paydet => paydet.PaymentID,
                                               (stat, paydet) => new
                                               {
                                                   InvoiceNo = paydet.Remarks,
                                                   paydet.Amount,
                                                   stat.Status,
                                                   paydet.PaymentCode
                                               })
                                           .Where(s => s.PaymentCode.ToLower() == "c")
                                           .GroupBy(g => g.InvoiceNo)
                                           .Select(lg =>
                                                   new
                                                   {
                                                       InvoiceNo = lg.Key,
                                                       TotalAmount = lg.Sum(w => w.Amount)
                                                   }).ToList();
```

Comment: If you're using LINQPad, you can click SQL tab after results to see the SQL query syntax.

Comment: that's the problem. I get an error when I copy this to Linqpad

Comment: I think it only accepts not the lambda method as input

Comment: AFAIK default LINQPad doesn't require the `db` instance, it automatically assigns with `[table_name] + s` suffix, e.g. `Trans_SAPStats`. Also seems that LINQPad accepts query expression keywords instead of lambda one.

Comment: yes unfortunately that's right. It just converts it to lambda afterwards

Answer (score 0):

If you have this code inside working application then try to use SQL profiler. Another option - linqpad

Comment: about Linqpad, I don't know how to do the starting code. the "db.[table name] I get an error

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  p.Remarks AS InvoiceNo,SUM(p.Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM Trans_SAPStat AS s
INNER JOIN Trans_PaymentDetail AS p ON s.PaymentID = p.PaymentID
WHERE s.EmployeeID = @EmployeeID 
  AND s.PaymentID <> @PaymentID 
  AND LOWER(s.Status) <> 'cancelled or'
  AND LOWER(s.PaymentCode) = 'c'
GROUP BY p.Remarks
```

Comment: nah, it returns different result

Comment: @ElbertJohnFelipe - Try my updated answer. If it doesn't work, please show me some sample data from both the tables.

Comment: it returns 4k+ rows. it should only return 54 rows

Comment: @ElbertJohnFelipe - Can you please show some sample data from both the tables? BTW, `@EmployeeID` and `@PaymentID` are parameters passed to your query.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the query to a variable without materialization (`.ToList()`), then just use `query.ToString()`. This will return the actual SQL query.

```
var query = db.Trans_SAPStat.Where(....); // don't call .ToList()
var sqlQuery = query.ToString();
var result = query.ToList(); // materialization
```

NOTE: This is the default behaviour for entity framework / linq to entities `IQueryable<T>` interface.